# Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?

Tags: flutter

When working with HIVE database in flutter. If you ever get error like this:

***"Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?"***

It means you haven't opened your box to

To resolve this issue call

**await Hive.openBox("boxname");**

before using the box

Comment: Plesae find ans in question

Comment: When you post a question, it gives you the option to answer your question. Make sure to check that and you should post an answer at least to make it clear that it's answered.  Make sure to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It means you haven't opened your box. To resolve this issue call

```
await Hive.openBox("boxname");
```

before using the box.

Comment: what is the box name?

Comment: final recentSearchs = Hive.box(AppConstants.resentSearchTag); How can I solve there the issue

Answer (score 1):

The box needs to be open either at the beginning, after database initialization or right before doing the operation on the box.

For example in my `AppDatabase` class I have only one box ('book') and I open it  up in the `initialize()` method, like below:

The whole application and tutorial is [here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580).

```
const String _bookBox = 'book';

@Singleton()
class AppDatabase {
  AppDatabase._constructor();

  static final AppDatabase _instance = AppDatabase._constructor();

  factory AppDatabase() => _instance;

  late Box<BookDb> _booksBox;

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    await Hive.initFlutter();
    Hive.registerAdapter<BookDb>(BookDbAdapter());
    _booksBox = await Hive.openBox<BookDb>(_bookBox);
  }

  Future<void> saveBook(Book book) async {
    await _booksBox.put(
    book.id,
    BookDb(
      book.id,
      book.title,
      book.author,
      book.publicationDate,
      book.about,
      book.readAlready,
    ));
  }

  Future<void> deleteBook(int id) async {
    await _booksBox.delete(id);
  }

  Future<void> deleteAllBooks() async {
    await _booksBox.clear();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the box you want to use and make sure to use **await** while using the openBox() function.

```
await Hive.openBox("boxname");
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this exception because I moved Hive initialization in a separate function and called it without `await`.

It was like this (working):

```
void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox('box');
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(child: MainApp()),
  );
}
```

Became like this (exception):

```
void main() async {
  initHive();  // should be await initHive();
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(child: MainApp()),
  );
}
initHive() async {
    await Hive.initFlutter();
    await Hive.openBox('box');
}
```

Without `await` the application does not wait for Future to complete and tries to look inside the box which is not yet opened.