# flutter opening a Hive box gives error -says box not found, Did you forget to call Hive openbox()

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I have a class where I am doing the graphql setup and the hive box setup. Here is the class -

```
class GraphQLConfiguration {
  ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = new ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient>(
    GraphQLClient(
      cache:
      GraphQLCache(store: HiveStore(Hive.box(HiveStore.defaultBoxName))),
      link: HttpLink('http://localhost:4000/graphql/',),
    ),
  );
  GraphQLConfiguration()  {
    initializeHive();
  }
  void initializeHive() async {
    await initHiveForFlutter(); // or await initHiveForFlutter();
    await Hive.openBox('bolBox');
  }
}
```

Now I initialize this class in the Flutter main method -

```
Future main() async {
   GraphQLConfiguration graphql = new GraphQLConfiguration();
}
```

When I run this code I get this error message -

Error - **Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?**

I followed this post as well [Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59436867/box-not-found-did-you-forget-to-call-hive-openbox), didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize Hive by giving it a home directory by using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

```
final Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
Hive.init(appDocDir.path);
```

then open box

```
await Hive.openBox('bolBox');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add initHiveForFlutter in your root folder & it solve the problem.

```
void main() async{
  await initHiveForFlutter();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Worked for me.

No need to initialise with open box & path as GraphQl handles that internally inside initHiveForFlutter.